# gradle project sync failed Android studio 3.1.2

Tags: android-studio, gradle

[gradle sync error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFEJl.png)

I just have installed my android studio v 3.1.2 in 32bit windows 7. It don't build or run anything in visual studio saying

> Gradle project sync failed

basic functionally will not work properly.

and in console it shows

> Gradle sync failed: CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1 is not
>   compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your
>   computer's system information to see whether you need a x86 (32-bit)
>   or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software
>   publisher
>                 Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (4s 276ms)

I have changed the environment path to **(C:\Gradle\gradle-4.8\bin)** newly downloaded **gradle 4.8 complete** file.
[environment variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5jkv.png)

what should i do now?????

Answer (score 0):

The error shows that you have installed 32-bit android studio while it requires 64 bit setup.May be the windows you are running is 64 bit .Check that and download setup accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Install 64-Bit Windows OS is the only way to solve this issue.
May be addressing problem.